# Error in filter function in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to google spreadsheet functions and trying to apply function as under:

I have sheet1 & sheet2 in one workbook (name-formula).

I want to display filtered column data from sheet2 & range C1:C6 in sheet1 and cell A2, formula mentioned is as under:

```
=filter(Sheet2!C1:C6, (D1:D6>= E1) * (D1:D6 <= E2))
```

Now concern is that data is loading as per function but it is not as per set criteria i.e. it is not in between E1 & E2

Please look the following link for detail

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OU04KcKUkUpJbPZ6m3yXhS0CO1xYEkwk9Wq-g4WauiQ/edit#gid=0

Comment: Hi, if you are refering to col D of sheet 2 you should use Sheet2!D1:D6. Your formula refers to cells E1 and E2. However the cells used in your sheet are D1 and E1. Also in the column D of sheet 2 are dates. The values in D1 and E1 are numbers. What is their function ? Do you want to filter between two given dates ? If so, take a look at the changes I made in your sheet.

Comment: Can I bother you to 'accept' my answer then ?

Comment: It would be my pleasure but how since you have written in comment and not in answer,

Comment: Wow... you are right.. been reading why to much of these threads apparantly.. Will add it as answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are refering to col D of sheet 2 you should use Sheet2!D1:D6. Your formula refers to cells E1 and E2. However the cells used in your sheet are D1 and E1. Also in the column D of sheet 2 are dates. The values in D1 and E1 are numbers. What is their function ? Do you want to filter between two given dates ? If so, take a look at the changes I made in your sheet.